# HTML пробельные символы типа &nbsp; в нормальную строку

Tags: javascript, dom

Есть редактируемый `div`, в смысле он `contentEditable`. Но когда пользователь вводит туда лишние пробелы, например, то они потом какми-то специальными символами становятся, и я не могу форматировать ввод. Скрин прилагаю. Подскажите пожалуйста как лечится

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

П.С. Подскажите как оформить вопрос, или хоть подскажите как эти спецсимволы пробела называются, а я подредактирую.

```js
const editable = document.querySelector('.editable');
const output = document.querySelector('.output');

editable.oninput = function () {
  output.textContent = this.textContent.replace( /  +/g, ' ');
}
```

```css
.editable {
    border:1px solid red;
    -webkit-user-modify: read-write;
}
```

```html
<div class="editable">редактируемое</div>
<div class="output">редактируемое</div>
```

Comment: как называется не знаю но это сокращение от `non-breaking space` т.е не перазрывный пробел

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `.replace(/(\s)+/g, "$1")`
2. `.replace(/\s+/g, " ")`
3. Если пользователь что-то вводит, то, наверное, не просто так.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79472/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-stanislav-sagan).